# Need to select before Dragging FabricJS Object

Tags: angular7, fabricjs

If I want to change the position of my Unselected or Un-active TextBox object, I have to select it before dragging it to new position. I rather want to move it by just moving cursor up to the object and only by single click on the object.

Answer (score 0):

I used **mouseover** event to handle this. Binding **mouseover** event to the object (in my case its **TextBox**) and applying **setActiveObject()** method on canvas by passing the object resolved this issue. Here is the code:

```
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
let text = new fabric.Textbox('Enter text here', {
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  fill: "#C0C0C0",
  textAlign: 'center',      
  borderColor: '#00c6d2',
  editingBorderColor: '#00c6d2',
  padding: 15,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  width: 300,
});
text.on('mouseover', (e) => {
  this.canvas.setActiveObject(text);
});
this.canvas.add(text);
this.canvas.centerObject(text);
this.canvas.renderAll();
```

Makrup goes as follows:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```